# Generalization of Gauss multiplication formula for $\Gamma(jm+kn+a);j,k\in\Bbb N$?

Tags: closed-form, gamma-function, transformation, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

A hypergeometric single sum, like a [Mittag Leffler function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html) uses the [Pochhammer symbol $(a)_n$ multiplication formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/16/03/0003/) to easily have a [univariate hypergeometric function $_p\text F_q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) closed form:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(1)_{kn}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(k^{-k}z)^n}{n!\prod\limits_{p=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac pk\right)_n}=\,_0\text F_{k-1}\left(\frac1k,\dots,\frac{k-1}k;\frac z{k^k}\right)\tag1$$

Similarly, if a hypergeometric double sum, with indices $m,n$, and summand including $\Gamma(jm+kn+a);j,k\in\Bbb N$ can be written with $\Gamma(m+n+b),\Gamma(m+b),\Gamma(n+b)$ instead, then it would have a [bivariate hypergeometric function](https://mdpi-res.com/d_attachment/axioms/axioms-10-00318/article_deploy/axioms-10-00318-v2.pdf?version=1637905442) closed form. However, the [Gauss multiplication formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/16/02/0004/):

$$\Gamma(jm+kn+a)=k^{k+mj+a-\frac12}(2\pi)^\frac{1-k}2\prod_{p=0}^{k-1}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{jm+a+p}k\right)\tag 2$$

only gives $\Gamma(jm+kn+a)$ in terms of $\Gamma(n+rm+c),r\in\Bbb Q$. Using Pochhammer symbol [addition formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/16/02/):

$$\Gamma(jm+kn+a)=\Gamma(a)(a)_{jm+kn}=\Gamma(a)(a)_{jm}(a+jm)_{kn}$$

and its multiplication formula has same problem as $(2)$ preventing a closed form for the double sum.

Is there any to write $\Gamma(jm+kn+a)$ in terms of $\Gamma(m+n+b),\Gamma(m+b),\Gamma(n+b)$ or an analogous method, like in $(1)$, but for a double sum?

Comment: Lol see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform "The Hilbert transform is a multiplier operator" .

Comment: @ErikSatie It would be helpful if the “multiplier operator” was one that could reduce $\Gamma(an+bm+c)$ into $\Gamma(n+m),\Gamma(n),\Gamma(m)$. It will be checked out. Thanks

Comment: See (3) in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/einsteins-derivation-of-emc2-revisited/ . Hope it helps...

Comment: Can you conclude ?

Comment: @ErikSatie “$f$ should be spherically symmetric”, which the gamma function is not and the argument $\frac{v\pm w}{1\mp vw/c^2}$ does not match the question’s proposed identity. How do you think we could use $(3)$?

Comment: Take the log no ?

Comment: @ErikSatie That gives $\ln(2)+\ln(f(v))+\ln(f(w))=\ln(f(0))+\ln(f(\frac{\dots}{\dots})+f(\frac{\dots}{\dots}))$. If log of the gamma function too, then we require a formula for $h(x)=\ln(\Gamma(x))$ or $\psi(x)$, after differentiating, but instead of the product of gamma functions, we would look for a sum over $h(n+m+a_j),h(n+a_j),h(m+a_j)$ to expand $h(an+bm+c)$. The $(\frac{v-w}{1-vw/c^2})$ does not seem to match.

Comment: See a bit after the article with hyperbolic tangent

Comment: You can make appear the gamma function via the spherical symetry .Just an idea ;-)

Comment: See also Tyma https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194124/a-relation-between-the-gamma-function-and-the-mobius-function

Comment: @ErikSatie This MO post is about simplifying an integral-sum expression of $\Gamma(s)$. but the MSE question asks for a gauss multiplication like formula. Please see the MSE question for why.

Comment: Yes I understand there is also a manner to write the Gamma's function using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula . See "Multiplicative notation"

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer just some representation for the Gamma function (which could help) :

We have $x$ a positive integer :

$$\Gamma(x+1)=-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x!}{n!\left(x-n\right)!}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\left(e^{-t}-1\right)^{n-1}dt$$

See https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.09699.pdf for other representations

Reference :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity

Comment: If this formula were used, then we would get $(an+bm+c-1)!,(an+bm+c-n)!$ in the integrand instead of $\Gamma(c+n),\Gamma(c+m)$, or $\Gamma(m+n+c)$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash See theorem 2 in the linked paper the formula with integral was just an example .

Comment: @TymaGaidash After an extrodinary effort in my brain see the reference

Comment: While Dixon’s identity would give $\Gamma(a n+b m+c)$ in terms of a sum containing $\binom{a n+c}{a n+k}=\frac{\Gamma(an+c+1)}{\Gamma(c-k+1)\Gamma(k+a n+1)}$, for example, it would give a triple series, the double series from the question and the Dixon identity sum, making it hard to put in terms of a bivariate, 2 sum, hypergeometric function. Do you have an idea of how we can continue?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Not really but see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_Hypergeometric_Theorem and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pfaff-Saalsch%C3%BCtz_Theorem there is some way to pursue it .